# Mount VMDK files with write access

Tags: gratis, windows-7, virtualization, hard-disk

I am looking for a freeware solution to mount VMDK files on Windows.

Requirements:

- Mount as drive letter
- Write access
- Windows 7 SP1 x64
- Freeware / gratis
- Commercial use allowed

I have already tried:

- [OSFMount](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html) but it does not provide write access
- [VMWare Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation) but it's a commercial product
- [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player) but that is not gratis for commercial use
- [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) can use VMDK files but only inside a VM, not map it as a drive letter without a VM
- [WinMount](http://www.winmount.com/winmount-free.html) but all download links return HTTP 404 (rev. 2015-06-24 13:07)
- [VMWare VDDK](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vddk/) does not include the `vmware-mount.exe` as proposed on other websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article [7 Ways To Open Virtual Hard Disk Images For Read And Write Access](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/access-virtual-hard-disks-easily-in-windows-7/) has a (still working) link to the older version of VDDK SDK for Windows 5.1.4, which includes [vmware-mount.exe](https://customerconnect.vmware.com/downloads/details?downloadGroup=VSP510-VDDK-514&productId=284).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).